# I can not get theme url (null theme url) when I get site theme default (no theme)

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Currently, I used sharepoint 2010, I used code below to get color of site theme, but it occurs exception (null theme url) when I get default (no theme). Please help me to get color of default (no theme).

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(this.Context.Request.Url.ToString()))
{
  using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
     string urlTheme = ThmxTheme.GetThemeUrlForWeb(web);                   
     using (ThmxTheme thmxTheme = ThmxTheme.Open(web.Site, urlTheme))
     {
        dark2 = thmxTheme.DarkColor2.DefaultColor.Name;                           
     }
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this. Because in SharePoint theme folder do not have theme with name is default.

Thanks

Nguyen